# File Broweer/Chooser vaadin

Tags: javascript, vaadin, file-browser

AFAIK Vaadin's File Browser is Coupled with Upload process . But in my case , I just need only the file browser (What I exactly need is to get the  path of the file to be uploaded).
Please let me know a way of implementing the file browser in vaadin.

Answer (score 1):

Please see also [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav).

In short: No, you can't get the path of a selected file with javascript. Only the filename is possible, due to security restrictions of the webbrowsers.

Comment: Not necessary to be in javascript . I would prefer to have it in vaadin

Comment: Vaadin is working with javascript on the client side. It's the only thing you can safely use today. You could use a flash or .net app on your system, but then all users will have to have the plugin installed.